# For which $n_o \in \mathbb{N}$ is it possible to show with induction that $2\log_2(n) \leq n$ applies?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

For which $n_o \in \mathbb{N}$ is it possible to show with induction that $2\log_2(n) \leq n$ applies? for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $ with $ n \geq n_0$?

How to proceed to such questions? Hope somebody can help

Comment: Why don't you just start computing something? Is it true that $2 \log_2(2) \le 2$? What about $2 \log_2(3) \le 3$? What about... ?

Comment: So is this the mathematical correct way to find it?

Comment: It's a way that works.

Comment: See the reference http://www.amazon.com/A-Dictionary-Inequalities-Peter-Bullen/dp/0582327482 , "A dictionary of inequalities".

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an $n_0$ which works and then we'll see which number it should be .

We'll try to prove $2\log_2(n+1)\leq n+1$ using $2\log_2(n) \leq n$ with $n \geq n_0$.

$n+1 \geq 2\log_2(n)+1 $ so we would want that $2 \log_2(n)+1 \geq 2\log_2(n+1)$ or :

$$\frac{1}{2} \geq \log_{2}{\frac{n+1}{n}}$$

$$\sqrt{2} \geq \frac{n+1}{n}$$
$$n \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} \approx 2.41$$

This should happen for every $n \geq n_0$ so every $n_0 \geq 3$ should make the induction work .

All we need now is to check the base case to find the minimal number that works (then from induction all the other bigger numbers will work )

$n=3$ doesn't work but $n=4$ works so the optimal $n_0$ to choose is $n_0=4$ (because $n_0$ works and also $n_0 \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}$ for the induction to work )